# Python: How to get rid of this TypeError?

Tags: python, constructor, typeerror

I am testing my object oriented programming file:

```
class Animal():
    def __init__(animal):
        if animal == "dog":
            print("Bark")
        elif animal == "cat":
            print("Meow")
        elif animal == "cow":
            print("Moo")
        else:
            print("No animal given")
```

It works fine, But if i do this:

```
animal = Animal("dog")
```

It gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/????/Desktop/Leahnn Files/testing/oop.py", line 12, in <module>
    animal = Animal("dog")
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

How do I get rid of this?

Comment: Did you mean: `def __init__(self, animal):`?

Comment: init function must have self in it please include that also, if not included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument of passed to `init` is always implicitly the constructed instance. You should handle this in the definition too:

```
def __init__(self, animal):
```